# How to implement a control magnification on key press

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, popup, implementation

I would like to implement the following feature:

When you press any specific button (event implementation is not so important), a window pops up with the magnified image of a certain region of the main window. And disappears when the button is pressed again.

Comment: So you want to toggle a popup's appearance on a key press event - that's easy. But also, you need the popup to contain a magnified part of the windows below the cursor?

Comment: @Maxim V. Pavlov, I have a control, or area of ​​the window, witch I would like to render on top of the window, in a larger size. I might put canvas on top of the window and make it visible or invisible, but how I can display with existed control?

Comment: Explain what do you mean when you are saying: "but how I can display with existed control?" P.S. I wish we could use Russian for comments here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This article provides an example and an explanations for **exactly** what is requested in terms of magnification.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/MagnifyingInWPF.aspx

It is in VB.NET, but the code is easy to translate into C# and reverse engineer it.